# do.call cbind - what attributes are needed?

Tags: r, xts, cbind, do.call

```
mat <- matrix(rnorm(1000*15, mean=1/100), ncol=15)
mat <- xts(mat, as.Date(1:1000))

test <- lapply(c(1:10), function(x) { 
  data <- mat[,c(1:x)]
  means <- xts(round(rowMeans(data), 4), index(data))
  means
  })

do.call(cbind, test)
```

This does not work and gives something like: c..0.3219..0.0894...0.0459..0.1554..0.0708...0.4475..0.1794..0.0017...

```
cbind(test[[1]],test[[2]],test[[3]],test[[4]],test[[5]],test[[6]],test[[7]],test[[8]],test[[9]],test[[10]])
```

Is like expected.

Comment: While not quite a 'bug', I do think this is undesirable behavior and have [opened an issue](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/xts/issues/248).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `Reduce(cbind, test)` will get you what you want.

Comment: Thanks Len! It's strange, however: I have always used do.call(cbind, test) like this, with a lot of different data, and never encountered any problems...

Comment: Your welcome. I think that has to do with the list containing of xts objects, but I am not 100% sure.